# 409 Conflict error with audio call

Tags: beatsmusic

I am testing the Beats api in the playground section of the developer site. When I try to use the Audio api call I get a 409 conflict error and the following response.

```
{
    "code": "StreamContention",
    "message": "Another device is currently playing music: web app"
}
```

I understand the error but the account is not logged in to the web app. I already logged out of the web app.

How can I fix this locking issue?

Answer (score 1):

You're running into a stream contention issue. Since only one device is allowed to play audio at any time you must acquire the baton by passing the acquire param with value 1 to the playback endpoint.

ie. acquire=1

Check out this documentation for reference: 
https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs/read/tutorials/Stream_Contention

Hope this helps, thanks!